# Django: ordering a queryset by dictionary added values

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm trying to sort a queryset of dictionaries to which I added some calculated values.

The process:

```
class Inventario(models.Model):
    codigo_kinemed = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    existencias = models.IntegerField(help_text="Existencias ", blank=True, null=True)
    valor_coste = models.IntegerField(help_text="Existencias ", blank=True, null=True)
    valor_venta = models.IntegerField(help_text="Existencias ", blank=True, null=True)
    fecha = models.DateField(help_text="Fecha de toma de datos", blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.codigo_kinemed)
```

I get a queryset from that.

```
inventario_diferencia = Inventario.objects.filter(fecha=ultima_fecha_cargada.fecha).values()
```

That returns a queryset of dictionaries. Then I iterate over that queryset and calculate some new fields.

```
for este in inventario_diferencia:
    este['stock_valor_venta'] = este['existencias'] * este['valor_venta']
```

I can print that calculated field with no problem in the template.

```
{{ inventario_diferencia.stock_valor_venta }}
```

**Ordering**

I want to sort that queryset by the new `stock_valor_venta`value I added.

When I try the usual queryset

```
inventario_diferencia.order_by('stock_valor_venta')
```

I get:

> Cannot resolve keyword 'diferencia_mes' into field. Choices are: codigo_kinemed, existencias, fecha, id, valor_coste, valor_venta

Those are the model´s original values, so no option to order by the new value. When I try to sort it like a dictionary

```
inventario_diferencia = sorted(inventario_diferencia, key=lambda t: t.diferencia_mes)
```

I get

> 'dict' object has no attribute 'diferencia_mes'

**Documentation**

In the Django doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#values states the following:

```
values(*fields, **expressions) Returns a QuerySet that returns dictionaries, rather than model instances, when used as an iterable.
```

Is my problem related to the "when used as an iterable" part of the statement? How can I sort that kind of querysets by added values?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into using [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/). You could create the a field that is equal to the product of your two fields then order by that in SQL.

```
from django.db.models import F
inventario_diferencia = Inventario.objects.filter(
    fecha=ultima_fecha_cargada.fecha
).annotate(
    stock_valor_venta=F('existencias') * F('valor_venta')
).order_by('-stock_valor_venta')

print(inventorio_deiferencia.first().stock_valor_venta)
```

Comment: What if I have an annotation relating a calculation from other query? Something like:  `venta_historica=ventas.filter(prod_codigo=F('codigo_kinemed')).aggregate(Sum("uds")).get("uds__sum")`

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I´ll start another question